# Oozie action Spark2 : Kerberos Delegation Token Error

Tags: pyspark, kerberos, oozie

I have a cluster cloudera 5.12 with kerberos, 
i can launch a simple pyspark script with spark2-submit with no error , but when i try to launch the same script with oozie , i get:

> Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], main() threw exception, Delegation Token can be issued only with kerberos or web authentication
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getDelegationToken(FSNamesystem.java:7503)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getDelegationToken(NameNodeRpcServer.java:548)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.getDelegationToken(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:663)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getDelegationToken(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:981)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:617)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1073)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2217)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2213)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2211)

my workflow is :

```
<workflow-app name="${wfAppName}" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
<credentials>

 <credential name="hcatauth" type="hcat">

    <property>

       <name>hcat.metastore.uri</name>

       <value>thrift://XXXXX:9083</value>

    </property>

    <property>

        <name>hcat.metastore.principal</name>

        <value>hive/_HOST@XXXXX</value>

    </property>

 </credential>

</credentials>

<start to="spark-launch"/>



<kill name="Kill">

    <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>

</kill>
<action name="spark-launch" cred="hcatauth">

    <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.2">  

            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>

            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>

            <master>yarn</master>

            <mode>cluster</mode>

            <name>TestMe</name>

            <jar>mini_job.py</jar>
           <spark-opts>
           --files hive-site.xml
               --queue interne_isoprod  
           --principal interne_isoprod@XXXX
           --keytab interne_isoprod.keytab                  
           </spark-opts>


            <file>${projectPath}/scripts/mini_job.py#mini_job.py</file>
            <file>${projectPath}/lib/hive-site.xml#hive-site.xml</file>
            <file>${projectPath}/lib/interne_isoprod.keytab#interne_isoprod.keytab</file>
    </spark>

    <ok to="End"/>

    <error to="Kill"/>
```

and the pyspark script is :

```
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":

   spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test_spark2').getOrCreate()
   print(spark.version)
   spark.stop()
```

i tried with and without sparkops with no luck

Comment: Usually the message is just a warning that must be ignored -- Spark does not expect that the tokens have already been procured by sthg else (here Oozie "credentials"), hence it always attempts raw Kerberos auth, but continues anyway.

Comment: oozie exit the action with this error